# How to display images in a table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am making a table whose data is dynamically changed with the following script. I also want to display the respective images of the groups beside the group names. When the group names will change, the image will also change.

The table works absolutely fine.

The image files are there in my ide, so the path mentioned is correct. However the images are not displayed.

```
<script>
    //$, jQuery

    var lookupTable = {
    Palm: "PM",
    Cedar: "CED",
    Oak: "OA",
    Chinar: "CHI"
};

var setGroup = function(groupName) {
    var t  = jQuery('<div></div>').addClass('group');
    var tn = jQuery('<div></div>').addClass('group-name').appendTo(t);
    jQuery('<img>').attr('src','/examples/media/images/'+ groupName.toLowerCase() + '.png').appendTo(tn);
    jQuery('<span></span>').text(groupName).appendTo(tn);

    return t;
};

    $.getJSON('https://service_program', function(data){

        var taf = $('#item1').empty();      
        var tar = $('#item2').empty();
        var tat = $('#item3').empty();
        var tao = $('#item4').empty();


        jQuery.each(data, function(idx, game){

            if (game['Category'] === 1){
                var tr = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(taf); 
            } else if (game['Category'] === 2) {
                var tr = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(tar); 
            } else if (game['Category'] === 3){
                var tr = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(tat);
            } else if (game['Category'] === 4){
                var tr = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(tao);
            }

            $('<td></td>').text(game['group 1']).appendTo(tr);
            $('<td></td>').text(game['group 2']).appendTo(tr);
            $('<td></td>').text(game['itemName 1']).appendTo(tr);
            $('<td></td>').text(game['itemName2']).appendTo(tr);

        });         
    });

</script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to append images to `td` not `tr`.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I am also getting the error groupName not defined.

Comment: But where is that variable `groupName` being defined?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Please have a look at the updated code. It is still not working though.

Comment: The function setGroup  is never called and where do you get the teamName from?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$('<td></td>').$('<img>').attr('src','/examples/media/image/'+ groupName.toLowerCase() + '.png').appendTo(tr);
```

Comment: This gave me another error. Would you kindly check the code I have updated? Could you suggest how I could improve on that?

Comment: Can you post a example of the json, then I will make a demo.